# How to set focus on the first input in all forms in a WinForms project?

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, input

I have one application built with WinForms with a big number of forms on it (approximately 90 forms) and now there is a requirement that when any form is opened the first input should get focused, so that it is ready for being typed into.

I imagine how to do that for a single form. We could run the following:

```
var firstInput = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault();
if (firstInput != null)
    firstInput.Focus();
```

That's fine, but replacing this on *every* form is not just a huge task, but also it is a tremendous amount of code duplication.

I wanted to do that for all forms at once. In that case I created a base class:

```
public class BaseForm : Form
{
    public void SetFoucsOnFirstInput()
    {
        var firstInput = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (firstInput != null)
            firstInput.Focus();
    }
}
```

And made all forms inherit from it instead of Form. The only problem is how do I call this method on all the forms after initializing the form. Is searched for some Form intialization event that I could subscribe to on the base class but found none.

How can I accomplish this in Windows Forms? Is there any way I can use my base class approach without needing to modify all 90 forms? Is there any better way? Or simply there isn't any way of doing it without modifying each form itself?

Comment: Are you familiar with tab order?  When creating UIs you should always set the proper tab order.  This also helps with screen readers to let the user know the label associated with a control.

Comment: Setting focus automatically on the first element of `Collections` control is not a good idea because the controls will be added to `Collections` of your form in the order you add them to the form and maybe you move them to different locations, for example the first `TextBox` of your form may be at bottom of the form. You should set Tab Orders manually at design time.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `OnShown(...)` in your base form:

```
public class BaseForm : Form
{

    public void override OnShown()
    {
       base.OnShown();
       SetFoucsOnFirstInput(); 
    }

    public void SetFoucsOnFirstInput()
    {
        var firstInput = this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>().FirstOrDefault();
        if (firstInput != null)
            firstInput.Focus();
    }
}
```

This methos will get called *once* every time a new form is shown.

But the more important thing is - that you dont have to call i yourself - the framework will do it for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use form **Load** event for setting focus.

[help in msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.load.aspx)